# Prove that $k(f+g)_{xx} = (f+g)_t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Prove that $k(f+g)_{xx} = (f+g)_t$, given that:

$kf_{xx} = f_t$ and $kg_{xx} = g_t$, for $f(x,t)$ and $g(x,t)$.

My understanding: I think we need to prove $(f+g)_{xx} = f_{xx}+g_{xx}$ and $(f+g)_t= f_t + g_t$. Stuck here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are $f_{xx}$ and $f_t$ denoting double derivative with respect to $x$/derivative with respect to $t$? If yes, the statement follows by linearity.

Comment: @Gibbs Yes, they are the partial derivatives. I also thought that it should be true because of linearity. But I am hoping someone could explain to me a little bit more about it, like in what condition would this be true etc.

Comment: Partial derivatives, like ordinary derivatives, are linear i.e. $(f+g)'=f'+g'$. This can be shown from the definition $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_o}\frac{f(x,y_o)-f(x_o,y_o)}{x-x_o}$ and the algebraic limit theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by under which conditions is that true? If $f(x,t)$ and $g(x,t)$ are functions such that $f_x(x,t),g_x(x,t)$ exist and are finite for any $(x,t)$, then $(f+g)_x(x,t) = f_x(x,t)+g_x(x,t)$. The same for derivatives with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(f+g)_{xx}=(f_{xx}+g_{xx})$,

and

$(f+g)_{t}=(f_{t}+g_{t})$,

since the differentiation is a linear operator.

Then:

$k(f+g)_{xx}=k(f_{xx}+g_{xx})=k f_{xx}+k g_{xx}=f_{t}+g_{t}=(f+g)_{t}$.